# When scripting "sudo apt upgrade" with bash on Ubuntu 18.04, how can you automatically bypass the "package configuration" screen?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, sh

Folks,
I've almost fully automated my script to do an initial software install from an Ubuntu 18.04 EC 2 image AWS.  When I run upgrade, several package configuration windows pop up and require user interaction.   Does anyone know how to bypass these messages?  I appreciate your help!
Best Regards,
Tom

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
```

[Package Configuration window that appears when you run "sudo apt upgrade"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJzT3.png)

Answer (score 2):

[Try this answer from superuser](https://superuser.com/a/939651/645284)

```
sudo apt update && sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt upgrade -y
```

Comment: Tom, This worked perfectly.  Thank you so very much!